# What does "put mileage on somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms-in-context

Could you help me to understand the meaning of **put mileage on you** in the following context, please? Thank you very much!

> But she could not let herself forget that he was the kind of guy who
>   would find his way past your guard, take what he wanted, and convince
>   you that it was what you wanted as well. He would run you in circles,
>   **put mileage on you,** and then go on to his next conquest without a backward glance. And you wouldn’t be able to complain, because he
>   hadn’t put up a pretense of being anything other than what he was.
>
> *From Rainshadow Road by [Lisa Kleypas](https://books.google.com/books?id=QbuwrBhDPj8C&lpg=PT102&dq=%22put%20mileage%20on%20you%22%20rainshadow&hl=es&pg=PT102#v=onepage&q=%22put%20mileage%20on%20you%22%20rainshadow&f=false)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I take it that she means that the man would 'use' a woman in the same way a person would use a second-hand car; drive it around for a certain time, adding to the wear and tear on it, then seek to pass it on to another owner.

Comment: +1 agreed. I would add that to my ear (lifelong California resident), this is not anything like a common idiom. this strikes me as a creative, literary bit of figurative language.

Comment: It's something I've heard elsewhere; while it *shouldn't* be idiomatic I would say that it is in certain areas among certain crowds.  I am more from the east coast and I can't specifically remember where I've heard it but likely in movies, at bars, from crusty sailor types, etc.

Comment: I feel like milage idioms are: someone with a lot of miles of them is prematurely-aged, and getting a lot of milage out of something means using it to the point it wears out. I've never heard "put milage on [someone]" either, but it seems like a combination of those 2.

Comment: @OwenReynolds also "it ain't the years, it's the mileage" is a common expression as well

Comment: This answer would be more useful to an English Language Learner if you would include a definition of "putting mileage on" a car.

Comment: I thought I had explained it as 'drive [the car] around, adding to the wear and tear'.